# Rails: How to display error message without model name, association name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to display error message without model name, association name.

For example, the following error was displayed,

```
Rooms events base To time must be after from tim
```

But I'd like to display only `To time must be after from time`.

The validate in my model is as followings;

```
validate do |e|
  if e.start_at.present? && e.end_at.present? and e.start_at > e.end_at
    errors[:base] << "To time must be after from time"
  end
end
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to display only `To time must be after from time`.

**application.html.erb**

```
    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %>
    <% end %>
```

**SOLVED!**

It works when I set the followings in en.yml

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your application.html above yield

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @Chakreshwar Sharma. I have `flash.each do` in my application.html as I added at the bottom of my question. So it would be appreciated if you could give me how to modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

`errors` is a hash. The key is the name of the field name or `:base` and the value is an array of your error messages as strings.

`values` on a hash will return an array of the values without the keys. Because the value in this hash is an array, we end up with an array of arrays: `[['To time must be after from time']]`

I use `flatten` to squash all of the nested arrays to a single top level array.

`join("\n")` will join all of the array elements into a single string, separated by a newline character.

Put it all together and you get something like this:

```
flash[:error] = @object.errors.values.flatten.join("\n")
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-values